# Пасринг сайта Python

Tags: python, json, requests

Есть проблема. Я парсю эту страницу: https://www.cian.ru/cat.php?deal_type=sale&engine_version=2&object_type%5B0%5D=1&offer_type=flat&p=54&region=1
Далее перехожу на каждое объявление и получаю: название, цену, вид из окон, тип жилья.
У меня получаются списки из названий, цен и т.д.
И проблема в том, что поля "Вид из окон" на страницы объявления может и не быть. Из-за этого возникает ошибка: `IndexError: list index out of range`

```
name_list = ['name_1', 'name_2', 'name_3', 'name_4']
price_list = [123, 355, 56, 7]
window_view = ["во двор", 'на улицу и двор']
```

И вот вопрос: Как мне проверить есть ли поле "Вид из окон" и если нет то в список добавить "none"
на выходе я получаю json:

```
[
  {
    "title": "home_1",
    "price": "123",
    "window_view": "на улицу",
  },
  {
    "title": "home_2",
    "price": "355",
    "window_view": "На улицу и двор",
  },
  {
    "title": "home_3",
    "price": "56",
    "window_view": "На двор",

  },
  {
    "title": "home_4",
    "price": "7",
    "window_view": "none"
  }
]
```

и тут при создании словаря с дальнейшей записью в json возникает ошибка: `IndexError: list index out of range`

```
for i in range(0, len(title_result)):
    to_json = {
        "title": title_result[i],
        "price": price_result[i],
        "window_view": window_result[i]

    }
```

если нужно вот полный код:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as BS
import json

url = "https://www.cian.ru/cat.php?deal_type=sale&engine_version=2&object_type%5B0%5D=1&offer_type=flat&p=54&region=1"
headers = {"user-agent": "тут user-agent"}

r = requests.get(url, headers = headers)
soup = BS(r.content.decode("utf-8"), "html.parser")

url = soup.findAll("a", class_ = "c6e8ba5398--header--1fV2A")

url = [i.get('href') for i in url]
result = []
title_result = []
price_result = []
window_result = []
home_result = []

for i in url:
    r = requests.get(i, headers = headers)
    soup = BS(r.content.decode("utf-8"), "html.parser")

    block = soup.find("div", class_ = "a10a3f92e9--section_divider--1zGrv")
    block_li = block.findAll("li", class_ = "a10a3f92e9--item--_ipjK")
    for i in block_li:
        type_home = i.find("span", class_ = "a10a3f92e9--name--3bt8k").text

        if type_home == "Тип жилья":
            type_home = i.find("span", class_ = "a10a3f92e9--value--3Ftu5").text
            home_result.append(type_home)
        if type_home == "Вид из окон":
            type_home = i.find("span", class_ = "a10a3f92e9--value--3Ftu5").text
            window_result.append(type_home)

    title = soup.find("h1", class_ = "a10a3f92e9--title--2Widg").text
    price = soup.find("span", itemprop = "price").text
    window_view = block.find("li", class_ = "a10a3f92e9--item--_ipjK").find("span", class_ = "a10a3f92e9--value--3Ftu5")

    title_result.append(title)
    price_result.append(price)


for i in range(0, len(title_result)):
    to_json = {
        "title": title_result[i],
        "price": price_result[i],
        "window_view": window_result[i],  
    }

    result.append(to_json)

with open("test.json", "w", encoding = "utf-8") as file:
    json.dump(result, file, indent = 2, ensure_ascii = False)
```

Заранее спасибо

Comment: В чем проблема обработать в try, except?

Comment: У вас такая ошибка потому в `price_result` и/или `window_result` элементов меньше чем в `title_result`

Comment: я понимаю, мне нужно проверить, если поля "Вид из окон" нет в объявлении в список добавить "none"

Comment: делайте сразу словарь с нужными полями, а не списки

Comment: так как решить?

Comment: помоги пожалуйста